Algolia autocomplete warning 'The attribute "..." described by the path ["..."] does not exist on the hit. Did you set it in `attributesToHighlight`?'
I have developed a web app with VueJS (Composition API) and use Algolia as my search engine. I followed the guidelines from Algolia to build a component for autocomplete and though it works, I get this strange warning in the console:
The attribute "city" described by the path ["city"] does not exist on the hit. Did you set it in attributesToHighlight?
"City" is defined as a searchable attribute and it is defined in my component as attributeToHighlight. When I use the autocomplete search and search for a city name, it does get highlighted, so I really don't understand why I get the warning.
This is the autocomplete component:
<template>
  <div id="autocomplete" />
</template>

<script setup>
import { algoliaSearchClient } from 'boot/algolia'
import { autocomplete, getAlgoliaResults } from '@algolia/autocomplete-js'
import { onMounted } from 'vue'

import '@algolia/autocomplete-theme-classic'

const INDEX_NAME = 'companies'

onMounted(async () => {
  autocomplete({
    container: '#autocomplete',
    placeholder: 'Search company',
    getSources ({ query }) {
      return [{
        sourceId: INDEX_NAME,
        getItems () {
          const results = getAlgoliaResults({
            searchClient: algoliaSearchClient,
            queries: [{
              indexName: INDEX_NAME,
              query,
              params: {
                hitsPerPage: 5,
                attributesToSnippet: [],
                attributesToHighlight: ['name', 'city'],
                snippetEllipsisText: '…'
              }
            }]
          })

          // console.log('Algolia results: ', results)

          return results
        },
        templates: {
          item ({ item, components, html }) {
            return html`
              <div class="aa-ItemWrapper">
                <div class="aa-ItemContent">
                  <div class="aa-ItemContentBody">
                    <div class="aa-ItemContentTitle">
                      ${components.Highlight({
                        hit: item,
                        attribute: 'name'
                      })}
                    </div>
                    <div class="aa-ItemContentDescription">
                      ${components.Highlight({
                        hit: item,
                        attribute: 'city'
                      })}
                    </div>
                  </div>
                  <div class="aa-ItemActions">
                    <button
                      class="aa-ItemActionButton aa-DesktopOnly aa-ActiveOnly"
                      type="button"
                      title="Select"
                    >
                      <svg
                        viewBox="0 0 24 24"
                        width="20"
                        height="20"
                        fill="currentColor"
                      >
                        <path
                          d="M18.984 6.984h2.016v6h-15.188l3.609 3.609-1.406 1.406-6-6 6-6 1.406 1.406-3.609 3.609h13.172v-4.031z"
                        />
                      </svg>
                    </button>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
            `
          }
        }
      }]
    }
  })
})
</script>

In my boot/algolia file, this is the definition of the 'companies' index:
companyIndex.setSettings({
  // Select the attributes you want to search in
  searchableAttributes: [
    'city',
    'country.label',
    'companyType.label',
    'companyNo',
    'contacts',
    'customerSince',
    'description',
    'duns',
    'facebook',
    'fullAddress',
    'healthScore',
    'industry.label',
    'instagram',
    'isReference',
    'linkedin',
    'name',
    'notes',
    'numOfContacts',
    'numOfOpportunities',
    'objectType',
    'objectLabel',
    'opportunities',
    'phone',
    'solutions',
    'state',
    'streetLine1',
    'streetLine2',
    'website',
    'zipcode'
  ],
  // Set up some attributes to filter results on
  attributesForFaceting: [
    'searchable(country.label)',
    'searchable(companyType.label)',
    'searchable(industry.label)',
    'healthScore',
    'isReference',
    'objectType'
  ]
})

The search index works without a problem. See these screenshots:



You don't have to add attributes for highlighting. By default all searchable attributes will get highlighted:

Does anybody have an idea why I get the warning and how to get rid of it?

Having checked all my company records I suspect (couldn't find them though) there were records in the Algolia index that missed the attribute "city". Having registered a city for all companies (or an empty string) via my app's UI has made the warning disappear.

On the Algolia dashboard, go to your index configuration and add city to the Attributes to highlight configuration.

Today the warning has come back. Very strange. Even with the suggested changes in the index configuration, the warning is given. And actually, after further reading, you don't have to define any highlighting attributes. If you don't, all searchable attributes will be highlighted by default. So, I am back to square one...

Do all your records have a value for attribute city? because the warning message is fairly clear "the attribute city described by the path ["city"] does not exist on the hit.

No, not every record has a city populated. But why does that return a warning? I mean, that's a quite common use case I would say.
